# Using REDUCE with Neo4j DSL

Tags: java, neo4j, dsl

So, I am trying to re-write the following Cypher using DSL.

```
  match (n) 
  where n.code =~ {prefix} 
    and n.code =~ '.*-(\\d+){5}' 
   with n.code as text, 
        '-' as mark 
   with reduce(
          last = 0, pos in range(0, length(text) - 1) | 
          case substring(text, pos, length(mark)) 
               when mark then pos 
               else last 
           end
        ) as idx, 
        text 
 return substring(text, idx + 1) as next 
  order by next desc 
  limit 1
```

Basically the idea is:

- given a structure with code like: "XXXX-00000". 4 chars and 5 nums
- when the input is the "prefix", as in the "XXXX-" part.
- find the last number in the "00000" part.

I am able not able to find any FunctionExpression to create REDUCE.
Am I looking at it wrongly? Or is it not yet implemented in 2.1.4
My dependency for this is as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-cypher-dsl</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: afaik reduce is not implemented in cypher-dsl.

Comment: `REDUCE` is in the latest version ( http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-functions-collection.html#functions-reduce ) but I'm not sure if it's in 2.1.4.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a much simpler way of doing this, using the [split function](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-functions-string.html#functions-split).

You can do this:

```
with split('XXXXX-00000', '-') as parts return parts[0], parts[1];
```

So how about:

```
MATCH (n)
WITH n, split(n.code, '-') as parts
WHERE parts[0] = {prefix}
return parts[1] order by parts[1] limit 1;
```